# how to test muti promise in one function with sinon

Tags: node.js, promise, sinon, sinon-chai

Here is my function, in this function, there are two promise function in the 'start' function. How should I test the 'start' function.

```
export class TTT{

fun1(){
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('function1');
        resolve('function1');
    }))
}

fun2(param){
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('function2');
        resolve(param);
    }))
}

fun3(param){
    console.log('function3');
    return param;
}


async start(){
    let param1 = await this.fun1();
    let param2 = await this.fun2(param1);
    this.fun3(param2);

}
}
```

And the next test file was wrote by myself. I stub fun1, fun2, and fun3, but it seems only first function works.

```
   describe('test',function () {
    it('test ', function () {
        let stub_fun1 = 
sinon.stub(TTT.prototype,'fun1').callsFake((param)=>{
        console.log('fun1');
        return (Promise.resolve('fun1'));
    });

    let stub_fun2 = 
sinon.stub(TTT.prototype,'fun2').callsFake((param)=>{
        console.log('fun2');
        return (Promise.resolve('fun2'));
    });

    let stub_fun3 = 
sinon.stub(TTT.prototype,'fun3').callsFake((param)=>{
        console.log('fun3');
        return 'fun3';
    });


    let handler = new TTT();
    let param = handler.start();
    console.log(param);

    stub_fun1.restore();
    stub_fun2.restore();
    stub_fun3.restore();
});

});
```

And, the result is

test

fun1

Promise {  }

✓ test

function2

function3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test contains race conditions. Stubs are restored before they are called.

`start()` promise should be chained:

```
it('test ', async function () {
    ...
    let handler = new TTT();
    let param = await handler.start();
    ...
});
```

Current setup requires `restore()` to be called manually. Stubs won't be restored in case a test fails. `mocha-sinon` can be used to omit `restore()`, set up a sandbox for each test and restore stubs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`async start` is promise function so in your test, you need to tell mocha by specifying `await` so it will run `console.log` after this function execution is finished.

```
describe('test', function () {
  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(TTT.prototype, 'fun1').callsFake((param)=>{
        console.log('fun1');
        return (Promise.resolve('fun1'));
    });
    sinon.stub(TTT.prototype, 'fun2').callsFake((param)=>{
        console.log('fun2');
        return (Promise.resolve('fun2'));
    });
    sinon.stub(TTT.prototype, 'fun3').callsFake((param)=>{
        console.log('fun3');
        return 'fun3';
    });
  })

  afterEach(function() {
    sinon.restore(); // use single restore
  })

  it('test ', async function () { // specify `async`
    let handler = new TTT();
    let param = await handler.start(); // specify `await`
    console.log(param);  
  });
});
```

The output

```
test
fun1
fun2
fun3
undefined
    ✓ test


  1 passing (13ms)
```

Comment: Yes, this way  can solve my problem. And also can use sandbox method to solve it. In sandbox way, could not use async and await.   var sandbox;
beforeEach(function () {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
});

afterEach(function () {
    sandbox.restore();
});

it('should restore all mocks stubs and spies between tests', function() {
    sandbox.stub(some, 'method'); // note the use of "sandbox"
}

Comment: if you use the latest Sinon 5, you don't need to use Sandbox for simple case like above code. https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/sandbox/ => "Since sinon@5.0.0, the sinon object is a default sandbox. Unless you have a very advanced setup or need a special configuration, you probably want to just use that one." :)